# Jumping to and selecting a link in the current visible part of the webpage in browser in MacOSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, browsing

I am trying to use only keyboards to browse webpages in web browser in macOS. The browsing itself is quite straightforward and when I have to select a link in any webpage using only keyboard, pressing tab and shift+tab works fine. But it becomes difficult when I have to select a link that is quite below in a lengthy webpage. In that case it becomes cumbersome to use tab to cycle through all the earlier links to arrive at the desired link.

Is there a way to quickly jump to and select a link in the current visible part of the webpage without cycling through all the links from the beginning using tab key?

I am open to any mainstream browser option such as Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Brave etc.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - that's not what the OP is asking. Syed - there's no way the browser 'knows' how many links there are, so the best you can do is step through forwards or backwards, whichever is quickest… or just click it ;-)

Comment: Did you want to popup all the page links then choose one?  Good luck (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for the cVim suggestion by JBCookin, I found a chrome extentsion called [Saka Key](https://github.com/lusakasa/saka-key) which is available for both Chrome and Firefox, which creates keybindings for the links or form elements for current visible page.

It worked perfectly for my need on clicking and opening urls in currently visible page in the browser using keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with [cVim.](https://github.com/1995eaton/chromium-vim) It is a browser extension that gives vim-like bindings to chrome. It has a feature called "link hints" that should provide a great solution to your problem.

Pressing <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, or <kbd>W</kbd> opens up the link hints, then you just type the character sequence ("link hint") displayed next to the link you want to navigate to. Using <kbd>f</kbd> opens the link in the current tab, using <kbd>F</kbd> opens the link in a new tab, and using <kbd>W</kbd> opens the link in a new window. You can even open multiple links by using the command <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and then typing the link hints for each of the links you would like to open in new tabs.

There are even more options you can map by editing the `.cVimrc` file. It is very similar to editing the `.vimrc` file to configure vim. I can add a guide here if necessary. For example there is a "search links" function that (similar to "find"/<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> on chrome but that only selects links). It is unmapped by default but you can remap by adding:

```
map <your-vim-binding> openLinkSearchBar
```

For example the vim binding I use for this command is `<M-/>`, meaning <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (it uses M because on linux this is equivalent to<kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>). The binding specifier follows vim specification, but the modifier keys don't match because I believe the person who wrote this extension used linux. `<C>` maps to <kbd>control</kbd>, '` maps to <kbd>command</kbd>, and I can never get <kbd>option</kbd> to work. [Here is the list of all the default key bindings in the documentation.](https://github.com/1995eaton/chromium-vim/blob/master/README.md#keybindings)

It is also very customizable because it allows you to map keyboard sequences to javascript code that executes on the webpage with ["code blocks"](https://github.com/1995eaton/chromium-vim/blob/master/README.md#code-blocks). If the built in features don't feel adequate, you can pretty much program whatever you want with the javascript code blocks.